# Is jQuery 1.4's new behavior a bad design choice?

Tags: jquery, api-design

This is a bit of a rant, but also a very serous question. jQuery has changed ajax param serialization as follows:

> jQuery 1.4 adds support for nested param serialization in jQuery.param, using the approach popularized by PHP, and supported by Ruby on Rails. For instance, {foo: ["bar", "baz"]} will be serialized as “foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz”.

Did you catch that?

You call your parameter `foo`. jQuery now renames that to `foo[]` behind your back if foo's value is an array. The reason for this is because some PHP-ers and Rubyists expect 3rd party APIs to rename things for them.

Call me old fashioned, but when I put something into a map, with key `x`, I expect to find the value under `x`. Or at least have this the default behavior with an optional override.

Even the documentation agrees with me:

> If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same
>   key i.e. {foo:["bar1", "bar2"]}
>   becomes '&foo=bar1&foo=bar2'.

Am I right in thinking this is simply a bad judgment call from the jQuery team?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually filling in a major inconsistency, *if* your deserializer is aware of the convention and works with it nicely. It makes an array-of-one-thing look different from a thing-on-its-own.

#### Old:

- `foo: "bar"` maps to `"foo=bar"` maps to `foo: "bar"`.
- `foo: ["bar"]` maps to `"foo=bar"` maps to `foo: "bar"`.
- `foo: ["bar", "baz"]` maps to `"foo=bar&foo=baz"` maps to `foo: ["bar", "baz"]`.

#### New:

- `foo: "bar"` maps to `"foo=bar"` maps to `foo: "bar"`.
- `foo: ["bar"]` maps to `"foo[]=bar"` maps to `foo: ["bar"]`.
- `foo: ["bar", "baz"]` maps to `"foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz"` maps to `foo: ["bar", "baz"]`.

And now everything roundtrips nicely and you don't have to worry about receiving array data or non-array data depending on how many elements were in the array to begin with. For maximum elegance, `foo: []` should also serialize to `foo[]` (a key with no value), indicating a 0-ary list, but jQuery 1.4 doesn't do that. Maybe it should. :)

Comment: OK, this is a *really* good point. And despite a vote to close this question I've actually learned something here that others can hopefully take away.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.  The old convention worked just fine, and continues to work fine for classic web workhorses like Perl's `CGI.pm`.  I think jQuery is just switching one working convention for another, and I don't know that anybody on either side is going to be all that happy.

Comment: surely the people on the side jQuery is switching to (PHP and Ruby developers, for starters) will be happy?

Comment: I've loved Perl for long enough to know that not only is CGI.pm's design *frequently* lacking, `param` is one of the worst parts. :)